# Chart JS - X-Axis base on timezone

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chartjs that data is base on timezone format. I dont know how can I change the timezone format using the moment.js in chart.js
Here is my xAxes

```js
scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: "time",
                        time: {
                            unit: 'second',
                            unitStepSize: 3600,
                            tooltipFormat: "MMM D, h:mm:ss a",
                            displayFormats: {
                                second: 'MMM D, h:mm:ss a'
                            }
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 15,
                            bounds: 'data',
                            autoSkip:false

                        }
                    }],
```

My xAxis data look like:

```
  xlabel = [1527206400000, 1527209672000, 1527209911000, 1527210151000, 1527210391000, 1527210631000, 1527210886000, 1527211126000, 1527211396000, 1527211666000, 1527211876000]
```

The xAxis keeps giving me the local time in my computer. I dont know how to make the setting into different timezone.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue, I need to show x-Axis date values in UTC, not local time.

Answer (score 2):

Chartjs graph convert the dates using LocalDateTime, I found this workaround which requires you to change the code of ChartJs graph - github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4334#issuecomment-386325799

or you could use a callback to generate the X-axis tick

```
ticks: {
  callback: (label, index, values) => {
      return moment.utc(label);
    }
}
```